# Migrating from a WP7 device to WP8

Tags: 8.0, 7.5

I currently have an LG E900 but get a Lumia 920 soon. Now I wonder whether there's an easy way of transferring all data from my old phone to the new one.

Years ago on two Nokia phones there was an application that synchronised them via Bluetooth but I haven't seen anything like that on today's smartphones.

Answer (score 4):

Nokia provides an App called [Transfer my Data](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/transfer-my-data/dc08943b-7b3d-4ee5-aa3c-30f1a826af02) which allows you to transfer Contacts and SMS from your old device to the new Windows Phone 8.

There are certain limitations though. All contacts except one were transferred from my Lumia 800 to my new Lumia 620. One failed and I have no idea why.

The second limitation - the far worse one - is that only the first 140 characters of your SMS will be transferred and only messages you received. All those SMS you sent will not be transferred.

The Apps you installed can be easily reinstalled through the Windows Store. There was an app called [Reinstaller](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/reinstaller/b9d1115b-2c0d-4e5d-afc6-fa6dcd84dda4) which did this automatically for you, but it doesn't seem to work anymore.

You should be able to transfer your pictures and music and such by synching them with your PC and choosing the same libraries when synching your new phone.

Answer (score 3):

As you are (propably) already using a Microsoft Account with your Windows Phone 7 device, these things will automatically sync:

- Calendar
- Tasks
- Contacts
- Mails
- Documents stored in SkyDrive (OneNote)

Now for music, pictures etc., you're going to have to load them onto your new device manually.

As for your texts / SMS, you can use the Transfer my Data app. Unfortunately, only the fist 160 characters will be copied and you can't Transfer your sent texts (at least thats what the app tells you). This is propably not going to work for you though, as this is only designed to work with Nokia Windows Phones.

For your apps, you can go to windowsphone.com/en-US/purchase-history to reinstall those you need.